# Android - Using Buttons With Single Layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have created an Activity that uses the ViewFlipper to Switch between Different elements. Each element represents an Item in a store. I would like to add a "Buy" Button to each View. I am however not sure how to do this, since all the views use the default layout i have created. I have added the information like the Price of the Item etc Programmatically. So i am uncertain how to add a listener to the button, since they will all refer to the same button in the xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/credit_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="220dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="104dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/credit_type"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/credit_button"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/credit_button"
    android:layout_marginRight="22dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:typeface="normal" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/credit_number"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/credit_button"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/credit_type"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

As you can see, the Button id is "Credit Button". So now to be able to differentiate between the different store items' buttons what would i have to do?

Note, i am adding store items dynamically as well, so i cant simply create all the views separately using xml.

OK HERE IS THE UPDATED ANSWER. I used everyones responses below to fix teh issue. So Thank you all :)

```
        // PerkView
    View PerkView = View.inflate(this, R.layout.store_category, null);
    viewFlipper.addView(PerkView);
    Button perkButton = (Button)
    PerkView.findViewById(R.id.StoreCatItem);

    // TitleView
    View TitleView = View.inflate(this, R.layout.store_category, null);
    viewFlipper.addView(TitleView);
    Button titleButton = (Button)
    TitleView.findViewById(R.id.StoreCatItem);

    // ProfileView
    View ProfileView = View.inflate(this, R.layout.store_category, null);
    viewFlipper.addView(ProfileView);
    Button profileButton = (Button)
    ProfileView.findViewById(R.id.StoreCatItem);
```

I simply Created Multiple Views Programmatically, and then retrieved the buttons from those views afterwards. I then added the listeners to the buttons as follows:

```
perkButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Perks.class);
            i.putExtra("player", player);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    titleButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Titles.class);
            i.putExtra("player", player);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

Thanks A lot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways you can handle the button click distinctly,

1. At the time of inflating layout for each store, add the button listener with onClick() method there only.
2. Or you can assign some uniqueId or flag to each store and then handle button click of store by this uniqueID.

Comment: On Time of Inflation, when i add add an onClick, how will i tell the program which item is selected?

Answer (score 0):

> Set unique tag for each store button, in code you can differentiate with respect to tags.Tag is just piece of information you want set for any view, u can use it.Implement on click listener in your activity and then set that to all buttons, so all buttons click run through same code where you can easily diffrentiate between ur store buttons with respect to tags.

like below how you can set and get tag

> ```
>   // for setting tag
>     Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
>     button.setTag("unique_tag");
> // get tag and then differentiate with the unique_tg
>     button.getTag();
> ```

Comment: Im not quite sure how to do this.

Comment: check update. please accept the ans and upvote if ur issue is solved

Comment: I will upvote your answer in a sec. But it doesn't illustrate how to use Listeners for the separate Buttons. Can i then use the tag to set a listener?

Comment: tag is just piece of information u want set for any view, u can use it. just implement on click listener in ur activity and then set that to all buttons, so all button will implement same on click listener code where u can esily diffrentiate between ur store buttons

Comment: Thank You. Could you make that part of your answer, so people will easily see it in the future :)

Comment: as u wished its their as part of ans,

Answer (score 0):

You can easily create your button programmatically like so :

```
Button b = new Button(this); // where this = your context
b.setText("Buy");
// b."other attribute" = "other value";
b.setTag("Awesome blue shirt");
b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Button buy = (Button) v;
        String article = b.getTag();
        // do some stuff
    }
});
container.addView(b);
```

You can identify the buy button using its tag, as seen here.

Comment: Im not sure as to what this line does: Button b = new Button(this); I mean in regards to the (this)

Comment: @user3011902 The constructor needs the context which the button should be in. And 'this' is telling the constructor about the context.

Comment: My Apologies i am really new to all this. The context refers to the current view it is in?

Comment: Actually, the context is available while in your activity (in the onCreate method) by writing "this", like in my example. It refers to the context linked with the activity.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you solve this by following stack:

**fragment** -has-> **list** -has-> **adapter** -has-> **list of items**

Normally if you present one item per screen and you want to swipe between you should use ViewPager with FragmentStatePagerAdapter (allows removing items from ViewPager if needed).

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html

For more items in one screen use ListView with BaseAdapter as it allows better control over item view and ListView will recycle views as you scroll or fling.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html